# Какому свойству в js , равно .width() в jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Какому свойству в js , равно .width() в jquery?

Comment: Вы не поверите, но [свойству](https://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/prop_style_width.asp) `width`. Всё, вопрос исчерпан или вы что-то другое пытаетесь выяснить?

Comment: @AK если свойство задано через CSS то я вижу выход только через `(window.getComputedStyle(el, null).getPropertyValue("width")` https://codepen.io/walfter/pen/eQryoO

Answer (score 1):

Если обратиться к [исходникам `jQuery`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/e743cbd28553267f955f71ea7248377915613fd9/src/dimensions.js#L11), то в зависимости от некоторых условий значение может соответствовать:

1. для window - `clientWidth`
2. для document - максимальному значению из `scrollWidth`, `offsetWidth` или `clientWidth`

В остальных случаях идет обращение к методу [`jQuery.css`](http://api.jquery.com/css/), который обращается к [cssHooks](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/354f6036f251a3ce9b24cd7b228b4c7a79001520/src/css.js#L335), которая в свою очередь вызывает [getWidthOrHeight](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/354f6036f251a3ce9b24cd7b228b4c7a79001520/src/css.js#L119) вычисляющую ширину или высоту.